# Posting a concatenated formula in VBA based on a newly created worksheet labeled as a date

Tags: vba, excel

I have a script which creates a copy of a worksheet with data on it, queries new data, and then uses a lookup (SUMIFS in this case) to pull any manual entries from the old sheet onto the new.  I am getting an application-defined/object-defined error message on the line that drops the formula onto the page (the last line below).  I attempted adding the formula directly instead, using .Cells, etc., but it must be in the language of the formula itself because I can drop a direct formula in this way (e.g. `.Range("N2:N" & LastRow) = "=M2*H2"`)

```
Dim CopySheet As String
Dim QSheet As String
Dim FormulaS As String
Dim LastRow As Integer
Dim CoreWB As Workbook
Set CoreWB = ActiveWorkbook
QSheet = "QData"
CopySheet = Format(Date, "mm-dd-yy")
With CoreWB
    .Sheets.Add(After:=.Sheets("HistSum")).Name = CopySheet
    .Sheets(QSheet).Cells.Copy _
    Destination:=Sheets(CopySheet).Cells
End With
FormulaS = "=SUMIFS(" + CopySheet + "!M:M," + CopySheet + "!A:A, A:A," + CopySheet + "!C:C, C:C," + CopySheet + "!J:J, J:J," + CopySheet + ",!E:E, E:E)"
With Sheets(QSheet)
     LastRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
     .Range("M2:M" & LastRow).Formula = FormulaS
```

Comment: Can you show the formula that is produced? Maybe `'`'s are missing from the sheet names?

Comment: I added a watch to the variable and it looks like this:  =SUMIFS('05-17-18'!$M:$M,'05-17-18'!$A:$A,QData!$A:$A,'05-17-18'!$C:$C,QData!$C:$C,'05-17-18'!$J:$J,QData!$J:$J,'05-17-18'!$E:$E,QData!$E:$E).  If I add in the single quotes to the formula as posted above, it still provides the same error.

Comment: use `&` instead of `+`.  vba is trying to convert the date to a number and adding it to a string.

Comment: I attempted this with and without the single quotes and still receive the same error message.  Example with single quotes: FormulaS = "=SUMIFS('" & CopySheet & "'!M:M,'" & CopySheet & "'!A:A, A:A,'" & CopySheet & "'!C:C, C:C,'" & CopySheet & "'!J:J, J:J,'" & CopySheet & "',!E:E, E:E)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

1. LastRow should be > 1
2. Use Long rather than Integer
3. There was a typo "," at the end
4. Add `'` before and after sheet name
5. Concatenate with & (as per comments)
6. Use Worksheets collection
7. I think you can just post to `destination Worksheets(CopySheet).Range("A1")` - but I could be wrong.

Code:

```
Option Explicit
Sub TEST()

    Dim CopySheet As String
    Dim QSheet As String
    Dim FormulaS As String
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim CoreWB As Workbook
    Set CoreWB = ActiveWorkbook
    QSheet = "QData"
    CopySheet = Format$(Date, "mm-dd-yy")

    With CoreWB
        .Sheets.Add(After:=.Worksheets("HistSum")).Name = CopySheet
        .Sheets(QSheet).Cells.Copy _
        Destination:=Worksheets(CopySheet).Cells
    End With

    FormulaS = "=SUMIFS(" & "'" & CopySheet & "'!M:M,'" & CopySheet & "'!A:A, A:A,'" & CopySheet & "'!C:C, C:C,'" & CopySheet & "'!J:J, J:J,'" & CopySheet & "'!E:E, E:E)"
    With Worksheets(QSheet)
        LastRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        ' LastRow > 1
        .Range("M2:M" & LastRow).Formula = FormulaS
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Well, that comma was unfortunate, but I still needed the rest of the help regardless.  Thank you both!